# Real Analysis Proof confusion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I've just received a solution to one of my assignments by our lecturer and I still don't understand a small bit at the beginning.

Suppose {${a_j}$} and {${b_j}$} are convergent sequences in $R^n$ with limits a and b respectively. Then

1. $αa_j → αa$ for any α∈R.
2. $a_j ± b_j$ → a±b.
   In the special case when {$a_j$} and {$b_j$} are convergent sequences in R we also
   have
3. $a_jb_j$ → ab.
4. $\frac{a_j}{b_j}$ → \frac{a}{b} so long as the $b_j$ and b are not zero.

I have completed all except the last one correctly.

Here is the solution up to where I'm confused.

We already know $a_j$ → a from a previous question. So I now must show $\frac{1}{b_j} → \frac{1}{b}$

So, Suppose $b_j → b$, where b $\neq$ 0

Then, for some J, where j$\geq$J implies

$|b_j-b| \leq \frac{|b|}{2}$ and here is where im confused, from my limited experience i would have thought $|b_j-b| \leq \epsilon$ and gone on from there. So, can someone tell why this has been done??

Edit: does the solution use some random $\epsilon$ and in this case they have $\frac{|b|}{2}$?

Comment: It’s not a random $\epsilon$: it’s a very specific one, which is indeed $\frac{|b|}2$. The fact $b_j\to b$ means that for **each** $\epsilon>0$ there is some positive integer $J_\epsilon$ such that $|b_j-b|\le\epsilon$ whenever $j\ge J_\epsilon$. Now take $\epsilon=\frac{|b|}2$.

Comment: @Brian welcome back!

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks! I don’t know how active I’ll be, especially since I’ve done essentially no math in the last three years, but I do hope to be around a bit.

Comment: I suspect that the point of this $|b|/2$ business is to show that, for sufficiently large $j$, all of the $b_j$"s and $b$ have the same sign. That will, in turn, be used to justify some multiplications or divisions of inequalities, where the sign can cause a reversal of the direction of the inequalities. I expect that arbitrary $\epsilon$'s will then occur later in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

If $b_j\to b\ne 0$ let $\epsilon_0=|b|/2$ and take $j_0$ such that $j\ge j_0\implies |b_j-b|\le \epsilon_0.$ So $$j\ge j_0\implies |b_j|\ge|b|/2  \implies \frac {1}{|b_j|}\le \frac {2}{|b|}\implies$$ $$\implies |\frac  {1}{b_j}-\frac {1}{b}|=\frac {|b-b_j|}{|b_j|\cdot |b|}\le |b-b_j|\cdot \frac {2}{|b|^2}.$$

So, given $\epsilon>0,$ let $\epsilon'= \epsilon \cdot |b|^2/2$ and take $j_1$ such that $j_1\ge j_0$ and such that $j\ge j_1\implies |b-b_j|<\epsilon'.$ Then $$j\ge j_1\implies |\frac {1}{b_j}-\frac {1}{b}|<\epsilon.$$

Comment: We could, instead, take $j_0$ such that $j\ge j_0\implies |b_j-b|\le |b|/ 10^{99}$ but "$|b|/2|$" suffices, & is easier to work with.